# Entity Framework limit length of a returned nvarchar column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I want to limit the length of a column in an EF query, ala:

```
 var query = from ce in entities.ContactEvents
              .Include("Person")
              .Include("Orders")
             where ce.PersonID = personID
             orderby ce.DateTimeContact descending
             select new ContactEvent 
             {
                  ID = ce.ID,
                  DateTimeContact = ce.DateTimeContact,
                  Description = ce.Description.Substring(0, 500),
                  Orders = ce.Orders
             };
```

The query fails because the EF can't project the complex type Orders.

> The entity or complex type 'Model.ContactEvent' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

I've tried a few different ways to do the same thing such as use an explicit join in the LINQ expression but so far I always hit a snag populating the Orders collection in the select projection.

Any ideas on how I can construct my query? Ideally I don't even want to use a select projection but I'm assuming I need to in order to be able to limit the length of the description column returned from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot project to entity types. That is the limitation. If you want to return projection (calling `select new`) you must either return anonymous type or custom non entity type. If you want to return entity type you must always return whole column from linq-to-entities. You can try to trim the column after object is materialized by using:

```
 var data = (from ce in entities.ContactEvents
              .Include("Person")
              .Include("Orders")
             where ce.PersonID = personID
             orderby ce.DateTimeContact descending
             select ce)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(e => new ContactEvent 
             {
                  ID = e.ID,
                  DateTimeContact = e.DateTimeContact,
                  Description = e.Description.Substring(0, 500),
                  Orders = e.Orders
             });
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to take the hit on pulling the extra bytes down from the database then :(.